# App crashes when clicking on TextFormField

Tags: dart, flutter, widget

I have a ListView which takes in a list of products. When tapping on a ListTile within the ListView, an AlertDialog is shown, which contains a TextFormField which allows the user to edit the name of the product.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _products.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        Product product = _products[index];

        return ListTile(
          title: Text(product.name),
          onTap: () {
            showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
                    title: Text("Edit name"),
                    content: TextFormField(
                      initialValue: product.name,
                      maxLines: 1,
                    ),
                    actions: <Widget>[
                      FlatButton(
                        child: Text("Save"),
                        onPressed: () {
                          // Save logic
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
            );
          },
        );
      });
}
```

The problem is that when tapping on the TextFormField, the app immediately crashes with this error:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building Builder(dirty):
Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable. To safely refer to a
widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling
inheritFromWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.
```

Can anyone advise?

Comment: do you have a stacktrace to that exception? Are you overriding the `dispose()` method for any widget?

Comment: Where are you testing this, I tried in iOS and it is working fine.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad I am testing on an iOS simulator.

Comment: @user2181948 Even I tested in iOS simulator iPhone XS and it was working as expected. Should I add a screen recording with some changes to your code?

Answer (score 0):

create from AlertDialog as a separate widget, this should solve the issue

Check this code:

```dart
class MyDialog extends StatefulWidget{
  final String productName;
  MyDialog({this.productName})
}

class MyDialodState extends State<MyDialog>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    reutrn AlertDialog(
                    title: Text("Edit name"),
                    content: TextFormField(
                      initialValue: widget.productName,
                      maxLines: 1,
                    ),
                    actions: <Widget>[
                      FlatButton(
                        child: Text("Save"),
                        onPressed: () {
                          // Save logic
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
            );
  }
}

// your onTap on ListTile should look something like this:
return ListTile(
          title: Text(product.name),
          onTap: () {
            showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) => MyDialog(
                    productName:product.name
              );
          },
        );
```